# How to write a function in javascript which returns true or false as alternating when its invoked without keeping global variables using closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

the function should be like `function trueOrFalse()`, it should not keep anything in global scope, everything has to be scoped local to the function. the returned value should be `true` or `false` and next time it should return the inverse.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A closure, as mentioned in the title, sounds like a good start.

Comment: functions are just objects - does that help - don't need *any* variables at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I wouldn't say that this is a duplicate, but rather a too broad question...

Comment: @GeorgeJempty , its not about `Closures`, but about implementing a particular logic using closures, its not a duplicate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. A closure and a local variable is all you need.

```
function gen () {
    let state = false;
    return function () {
        return state = !state;
    }
}
const trueFalse = gen();

trueFalse() //true
trueFalse() //false
```

Regarding the comment, it's possible to do this without a closure using a property on the function itself.

```
function trueOrFalse () {
    return trueOrFalse.state = !trueOrFalse.state;
}
trueOrFalse() //true
trueOrFalse() //false
```

Comment: yes, but can you write it exactly as asked: `function trueOrFalse() {...}` and no other code?

Comment: @georg Yes, you could use a property on the function itself